# Redirect a Page Through a Clicked Link

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

*
***EDIT: The duplicate answers weren't of help because those answers
involve using a File manager to edit the links, when my question
specifically asked how to use a link, or other source, to
redirect an other link. The example above shows exactly what I want
to happen.***

Is there a way to make a site redirect without the .htaccess or altering any file? I am trying to make it so that, when a link is pressed, a page will redirect to another page, ***sans editing the code in the files themselves.***

I am assuming this requires PHP, but I have no preferences on what I desire.

Example:

When I go to this link, - /redirect.html
It will take people on this link - /wait
...to this one - /round/2

If I am being too vague, please tell me what I should add to this to get my answer, as I am new to this site and the asking process.

Comment: Can do it in PHP, HTML or Javascript which one would you prefer?

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn to ask specific question to get quick and appropriate help.

Comment: As I said, I don't have any preferences, except for the fact that I don't want any form of redirection that will involve editing the file directly, but rather for quick and easy access so that when I go onto a link, the page will redirect. Of course, this doesn't mean I don't want to use code to form this kind of link, but just to redirect it when it's complete. Is this possible?

Comment: If you are seeking an htaccess solution.  It is mentioned once in one of the duplicates.  There is a multitude of questions on SO regarding this topic.  Begin your search.   If you don't know how to implement this technique update your question with what you tried.